# Как делать адаптивную верстку? С чего начинать?

Tags: html, css, frontend, scss

Нужно ли для начала сверстать макет по размерам своего экрана, а потом уже делать адаптив? Или сразу прописывать медазапросы начиная от экрана смартфона и до широкоформатных?

Comment: лучше конечно и проще сначала сверстать все для одного экрана полностью, а затем уже на каждый экран делать.

Comment: медиа запросы решат эту проблему

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от подхода и наличия макетов под те или иные разрешения.
При "Mobile First" подходе в первую очередь верстается под смартфон и после идет раскрытие до Desktop экранов.
В ином случае начинаете с Desktop макета и "сворачиваетесь" до смартфонов.